# How do you make cheap asian instant noodles without noodles?

Tags: seasoning

So, I have been falling in loving with the yum yum instant noodles. And the reason might seem a little odd. I usually add a lot of extra water when making them, because I enjoy them as "a soup". that is I like the flavour and taste the seasings add to the boiling water, and I easily would eat them without the noodles.

Now the thing is, I don't wanna buy a package of them just for the seasonings and throw the noodles away.

To clarify, I am not necessarily  interested in "recreating" the yum yum seasonings, but I was wondering how I could make such a soup myself in larger quantity without having to buy the noodles.

Comment: Can you list the ingredients on your favorite flavor packets - some things that sound like a chemistry kit to you might give obvious hints to others here... how well versed, by the way, are you in the concept of the six (or five depending on who you ask) basic tastes?

Comment: Most noodle flavor packets are some stock powder and MSG.

Comment: Boy are you in luck. There is a instant ramen fanatic on youtube called Alex that created A LOT of different ramens. here's his playlist form this adventure https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLURsDaOr8hWXGHjXPa3nTFZnbqJcAfs4N

Answer (score 1):

Trying not to interpret this as a recipe request, but a question about how to approach recipe mimicry.

Look at the ingredient list of flavourings you like. Try and sort them by function: six basic tastes (umami/sweet/sour/bitter/salty/fat), aromatics (spices, alliums of any kind, and other vegetables and vegetable extracts), textural modifiers (eg starches, emulsifiers), and stuff you do not need in a fresh recipe (preservatives etc.). Develop a recipe from there. Pay attention to oil vs water vs alcohol solubility of aromatic compounds.

or/and/also

Look at what dishes the seasoning is based on (eg japanese ramen broth+tare combinations, thai curry, chinese soups) - then look at recipes for these dishes, optionally cook some of them from scratch (you will be working with about a half to three dozen flavour defining ingredients, and get to know all shelves at your asian grocer's), to get an understand for the seasoning profiles.

Also learn about stock making - bone broths etc. if you want it meat based. If vegetarian, experiment with shiitake/kombu dashi, and fermented ingredients like all the varieties of soy sauce (hint: you want some thai/chinese light 
 and/or gukganjang), gochujang, douchi, sufu, chinese pickles, kimchi....

BTW, you will arrive at a point where you make broths that are just too intense without noodles...